# Rails db:schema:load in production when migration files deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've removed my migration files thinking that it shouldn't matter since I could load from the schema. However, I'm getting warnings in heroku that it could be destructive.

Is there a safer way to update your db from the schema when your migration files are deleted?

Comment: What's the problem restoring migration files which were not executed on production, and deploy it again?

Comment: I can definitely retrieve them from VCS, but I'm just wondering if there's a way to update db from schema instead. Might be handy when the number of migration files becomes too large.